# How do I update text inside CDATA

Tags: c#, .net, cdata, xmlnode

I want to replace text inside cdata section but when I simply trying to add text to it I lose CDATA definition.

I have a XML like this:

```
<title><![CDATA[string]]></title>
```

When I try to update this field with new value:

```
myXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText = TextBoxName.Text;
```

Output is

```
<title>string</title>
```

How do can I keep it as CDATA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title element will have an CData child which needs to be cast like so:-

```
 ((XmlCDataSection)myXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("title").FirstChild).Value = TextBoxName.Text
```

Comment: I was suspecting this was the way to do it, though you beat me to it while checking up the XmlCDataSection class.

Comment: Beat me too, though it does require a (obvious) cast.

Comment: @Matthew: Does something else need a cast?  I don't see it?

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
myXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("title").FirstChild.InnerText = TextBoxName.Text;
```

That way you don't have to deal with the CDATA format in your code (edit: 
hard-coding <![CDATA[ doesn't work anyway, as pointed out by  Anthony)